# iOS - Watermark video with transparent video

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I am using AVFoundation to watermark a video with another video that has transparency in it. I have managed to overlay one video on top of the other using the following code, but as soon as I start using an asset with transparency in it, the export fails without any helpful error.

[This link](https://figure53.com/docs/qlab/v3/video/video-cues/) talks about PreRes 4444 being the only codec that AVFoundation supports when it comes to alpha channels, but I cannot find any official documentation on that. The file that I am currently trying to add as an overlay is an H.264 encoded mp4, which seems to be the best choice after reading [Learning AVFoundation](https://books.google.com/books?id=JoAhBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=prores%204444%20avfoundation&source=bl&ots=aOkv2WJyPb&sig=71_oNMMjttSJYRG_f2Ohpc419pY&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-m9nX7-XOAhUC7SYKHXlIBU0Q6AEISTAF#v=onepage&q=alpha&f=false), where it states that

> The ProRes codecs are available only on OS X. If you're developing
>   only for iOS, H264 is the only game in town.

I can always fall back to adding an animation layer instead of a video overlay, but I would be surprised if there were no solutions to this.

```
- (void)addWatermarkToAsset:(NSURL *)assetURL completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURL *videoURL))handler
{
    AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];

    // This asset contains an alpha channel, and has a shorter duration than videoAsset
    NSURL *animationUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"InstagramAnimation" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    AVURLAsset *animationAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:animationUrl options:nil];

    AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                        preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
                        ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                         atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *animationTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                            preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    [animationTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, animationAsset.duration)
                            ofTrack:[[animationAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                             atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videoLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.7f,0.7f);
    CGAffineTransform move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(230,230);
    [videoLayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, move) atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *animationLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:animationTrack];
    CGAffineTransform secondScale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f,1.5f);
    CGAffineTransform secondMove = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);

    [animationLayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(secondScale, secondMove) atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videoLayerInstruction, animationLayerInstruction, nil];

    AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
    mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    mainCompositionInst.renderSize = videoTrack.naturalSize;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    exporter.outputURL = url;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
        });
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by doing a
  1. custom transparency format inside H264, and a
  2. custom (perforce) compositor of the custom transparency format

The custom format was a "tall" video, where each colour frame was directly  above its black and white mask.

The compositor took frames from the watermark and file-to-be watermarked, composed them, and wrote the result to a 3rd file. 
Each pixel of each frame was interpreted as a YUV value, one used as a  colour, the other a mask, and combined with the background frame.

To make it fast, the compositor was OpenGL pixel shaders + TextureCaches, although today you'd use [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) and `CVMetalTextureCache`s I suppose.

Comment: Big thanks. I ended up translating the AfterEffects animations into custom animations in code, since the solution with OpenGL shaders seemed too time-consuming right now. But will definitely try out your solution.